# Fortify Insecure Redirect ... but redirecting to your self?

Tags: asp.net, owasp, fortify

I've an ASP.NET web application project that I scan through the Fortify Source Analyzer v3.1.

The web project contains an ASPX that has a case where it redirects to itself.

The code is:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
```

Fortify classifies that as  OWASP A10 and CWE / SANS ID 601 issue.
I don't understand the vulnerability -- it seems that we're redirecting to a very specific place ... the current URL.

Why is that considered bad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't hurt to validate the data coming out of Request.Url is sane.  I don't know enough about .NET to answer real intelligently, but often URLs contain user provided content.  Could there be a QueryString? Is there a fragment (#foo) with further data after it? Is part of the path completely fungible, like in "http://server/search/foo"? Is it one of the fancy internationalized URLs? and if so, what character set is the string returned to you in? Could the remote attacker have specified a different hostname and/or Host header?

I don't feel comfortable that this is a drop-dead false positive.  Hopefully we can get somebody smart to chime in...

Comment: Makes sense.  I had not considered a Query String - so for a general case I agree this is not a drop-dead false positive.

Answer (score 0):

In general, SCA is looking for ANY unvalidated data coming from the user that is not validated in any way and used directly. The pattern it matched saw data coming in `Request.Url.ToString()` and then used `Response.Redirect(*)`. The specific source is more than likely irrelevant in this case; only that user supplied data was unvalidated when it was used.

If you could provide the RuleID I may be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: It's rule-id A232C1F9-8B44-43A4-89DE-835653DC5803.

Realistically, in the spirit of tightness...would a user or something actually be able to make Request.Url into someting that _is not_ this very page?  

I suppose one could make sure that the Path of the Request.Url was some hard-coded value (making the assertion that the code-file-name at build time ... is the ASPX page name at run-time) and I presume that would satisfy SCA...or is particular pattern **always** a false positive?

Thanks in advance.